# Magento 2 CMS page add custom breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-pages, breadcrumbs

I have tried the below code for Magento 2 cms page custom breadcrumbs, but I got this error :

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'action': This
>   element is not expected. Line: 3

Admin login -> Content-> Pages -> Add New Page -> Design -> Layout Update XML

```
    <referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string"></argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/xxxxxx</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: do you want custom breadcrumb for single page?

Comment: Yes, I want every CMS page have separated breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">cms_page</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/xxxxxx</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">yyyyyy</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Its append exiting breadcrumbs.
Like Home >> sample page >> Home >> XXXXXX >> YYYYYY.
Kindly hep me to solve.

Comment: Hi VijayS91. I don't understand what you mean. It is like this?  same my image -( https://prnt.sc/h3shw2 )

Comment: @VijayS91: The above will work. You have to change the crumbName to "home" instead of "Home" and for the second item "cms_page". Then clear your cache and check in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this its working for me

> Admin login -> Content -> Pages -> Add New Page -> Design -> Layout Update XML

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs.cms">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
                </argument>
            </action> 
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">CMS Page</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">CMS Page</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">CMS Page</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/cms-page</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">CMS Sub Page</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">CMS Sub Page</item> 
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">CMS Sub Page</item> 
                </argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>
```

Preview

> Home >> CMS Page >> CMS Sub Page

Comment: Thanks for this one! Worked perfectly in my Magento 2.3 installation. Great Job!

Answer (score 0):

You can to use **referenceBlock** instead **referenceContainer**:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string"></argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">XXXXXX</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/xxxxxx</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">YYYYYY</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

It's work for me well. I hope it will help.

Comment: Its not working shown this error :      Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1

Comment: It's very oddly. What is your Magento version? I tested it on 2.1.4

Comment: Admin login -> Content-> Pages -> Add New Page -> Design -> Layout Update XML
Added your code in this text-area and filled necessary fields. Then click the save button shown above comment error. 
I am work in Magento 2.1.8 version.

Comment: In 2.1.4 this code working properly. If you want showing only your items in breadcrumb - you can set option to `No` in `Stores -> Configuration -> tab "General" -> Web -> tab "Default Pages" -> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why above answers fully recreating the breadcrumbs. There's likely nothing wrong with the "Home" breadcrumb and you might get confused as to why the breadcrumbs are positioned differently. Additionally I highly recommend to add `translate="true"` to the title/label so they are ready for i18n. This would be the minimum needed:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">XXX</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">XXX</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">XXX</item>

            <!-- Remove this "link" for the last breadcrumb / to make it non-clickable -->
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/xxx</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```